# Writing to an android persistantfilepath Unity3d it only writes an empty file?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

I have this code below which should download a file and write to the `PersistentFilePath`, but instead it just flat out refuses to write on Android. The code below does work on PC and Mac but as I said it will write only an empty file which is of no use. Even after adding the  to an external manifest it still does not write. Is there anything wrong with my code or does anyone know how to do this?

(Revised simple question: My file will not save correctly on android but will on PC is there anything wrong with my code?)

I have already tried the external manifest file which just made my game crash.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using Mono.Data.SqliteClient;

public class MoveDB : MonoBehaviour {

    string webpath;
    string filename;


    IEnumerator Start() {
        webpath="www.google.com/";
        filename="thiswhatever";
        WWW www = new WWW(webpath + filename +".zip");
            yield return www;
            var progress1 = www;
        string fileName1 = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + filename+".zip";
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(fileName1, progress1.bytes);
            //Debug.Log("Cache saved: " + dataSetPath + fileName1);
            print("file download is done");

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + filename+".zip")) {
                print(" file does exist");}else{
                print(" file does not exist");}
        }
}
```

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before using them. `unity` tag had nothing to do with Unity game engine.

Comment: Are you sure you have successfully downloaded the data you're accessing via WWW? I see no check for www.error here. There will be no data, resulting in an empty file, if this isn't successful. I'd recommend trying something like writing a local string to make sure your code works to further identify the issue.

Comment: It does work when i go to the persistentfilepath it is there its just empty also it works on windows

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that www is correctly downloading the file you're trying to access? It is not guaranteed to be successful.

Comment: I will just add a txt debug and upload the screenshot give me 2 minutes

Comment: http://imgur.com/32XVihd,Nid4Xx2,NXz0MBm,OgtMqLa click the next picture to see the sequence of pictures

Comment: @albaslayer As you've been told twice already, your code should be checking [`www.error`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW-error.html) for response status. It's possible that you're getting an empty file because of some other error. Please let us know what error, if any, you are seeing.

Comment: As i said there is no error with my www I just did   if (www.error == null) {
   Debug.Log ("WWW Ok!: " + www.text);
  } else {
   Debug.Log ("WWW Error: " + www.error);
  }
  }and i got the response WWW Ok!

Comment: @rutter any help ? It will download picture files but will not download database files